# C# - How to write a Leave Event for a textbox that has been created dynamically

Tags: c#

I have a dynamically created text box.  I want to register a function on the Leave event.  How do I do that?

```
textbox = new TextBox();
```

Comment: An example for text changed event. `textbox.TextChangedEvent += theEventMethodName;`

Comment: What is the event for leave? - not textchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
 textbox.Leave += new EventHandler(textBoxLeave);
```

actual handler:

```
    private void textBoxLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // put your code here
    }
```

Comment: Ah - so no special handler like the KeyPressHandler - I'll give that a try

Comment: Note that the `new EventHandler()` syntax is superfluous these days.  `textbox.Leave += textBoxLeave;` would be just fine, and shorter.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot What .Net version makes this the case?

Comment: @KSdev It looks like delegate inference was introduced in .NET/C# 2.0

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Good to know, was unaware of this.